# Python - PyMQI - Get a message from a queue MQ using parameter

Tags: python, ibm-mq, pymqi

Using the module pymqi how do you get a message in MQ queue using a parameter, for example "UserIdentifier"? So, I would only get messages from the queue that possess this parameter "UserIdentifier". Thank you for your attention.

Comment: Is it part of message selector (JMS) or MQMD.UserIdentifier?

Answer (score 0):

You can only get messages by MsgID, CorrelID or GroupID.

Answer (score 0):

For the MQGET (MQGMO.MatchOptions) the option avaible are:
MQMO_MATCH_MSG_ID
MQMO_MATCH_CORREL_ID
MQMO_MATCH_GROUP_ID
MQMO_MATCH_MSG_SEQ_NUMBER
MQMO_MATCH_OFFSET
MQMO_MATCH_MSG_TOKEN
and obvious:
MQMO_NONE

I think this is self-istalling.

Source:
http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wmqv7/v7r0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.mq.csqzak.doc%2Ffr10850_.htm

Although is expensive you can Browse for message and then Get, it depends on what and where you are working.